# why sorting alogrithim is going to infinite loop

Tags: c++, arrays

My code: (i expect it sort passed array into ascending order).

```
void sort( int arr[], int n) {
    int c=0;

    for(int i = 0; i<n-1; ++i) {
        if (arr[i]>arr[i+1]) {
            c=arr[i];
            arr[i]=arr[i+1];
            arr[i]=c;
            i=0;
        }
    }

}
```

example array: `int arr[4]={3,1,2,4};`

```
sort(arr,4);
```

**Error:** Infinite loop???

Comment: Step through the code manually-on-paper (or with a debugger), for a small input set. Why is the termination condition not met?

Comment: i've been doing that for embarrassingly 2 hours. I mean if array is 3,4,1,2.. The process should go like this: 3,1,4,2....1,3,4,2 ... 1,3,2,4 ..1,2,3,4..

Comment: "i" see what you did there :)

Comment: @user2864740: How is it not "in bounds"?

Comment: @MuhammadUmer: Ok, so let's see your working.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thanks for pointing that out; I misread the termination equality :<

Comment: `arr[i]=c;` Typo here :)

Comment: People should stop downvoting this question.  While it lacked an SSCCE, at least it had the input he was giving into the function, and a description of the expected output and actual output.  I upvoted the question to counteract the negativity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code for swapping two consecutive elements in the array is wrong.  Replace the first three lines inside the if statement with:

```
c = arr[i];
arr[i] = arr[i+1];
arr[i+1] = c;
```

The last line is the one I fixed.

This algorithm is called a [bubble sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort).

**EDIT:** Another thing you need to do to ensure correct sorting is to set `i` to `-1` instead of `0` at the end of the if statement.  If you just set it to 0, then on the next iteration of the loop it will get incremented and become 1, which means that your code will not consider swapping the first two elements of the loop.  (Thanks to the comment from Anton Savin.)

Comment: @MuhammadUmer also set `i = -1` instead of `0`, otherwise for example you will sort incorrectly `{3, 2, 1, 4}`

Comment: He would never have gotten an infinite loop, though the sorting would be a no-op. Question broken.

Comment: @Lightness:  Wrong.  Suppose the list is  [3, 2, 1].  You will need to swap the first element multiple times to get it sorted, at least with the algorithm the OP is using.  The first swap will put the 2 at the beginning, and a the second swap of that position will put 1 at the beginning.

Comment: thanks a billion, even though i always knew for loops execute `i++` at the end of every loop for some reasons i never thought of 0 becoming one. i can't select this answer right.

Comment: @DavidGrayson: Right, yes, true :)

Comment: David Grayson is right, here is why: if 1st 2 elements are sorted (2,5) and if third element happens to be 2,5,3...can you say it's sorted now.